# API Connect developer portal how to post file to one file

Tags: curl, visual-recognition, apiconnect

curl -X POST -F "images_file=@prez.jpg" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/detect_faces?api_key={api-key}&version=2016-05-20"

this is a sample curl post command to post one image file to api connect.

I published this api to api connect developer portal. but don't know how to post image file to my api using api connect's format.

api connect example:
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com/wlwwucnibmcom-dev/ibmtesting/vision5/classify \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'x-ibm-client-id: REPLACE_THIS_KEY' \
  --header 'x-ibm-client-secret: REPLACE_THIS_KEY'

which format I should use to post my request???

Comment: In your first cURL command, you are sending images_file, but in the second one, I don't see any actual data being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Using the API Designer you can test your APIs. The designer also provides examples for each API call, including cURL syntax that you are looking for:
[image]

An example is provided in the documentation:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://localhost:4002/api/notes \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'x-ibm-client-id: default' \
  --header 'x-ibm-client-secret: SECRET' \
  --data '{"title":"Buy eggs and milk"}' -k
```

For more information please follow the **Explore Your REST API** section in the [Getting Stated: Run Your API](https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/getting-started/run-your-api/) documentation.